# How to *optimally* solve scheduling N jobs with (arrival_time, execution time) known in advance so the average wait time for N jobs is minimum?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, scheduling, job-scheduling, np

Can someone explain how one can optimally solve this problem?

It's clear that a greedy approach wouldn't produce the optimal solution even though the these two links say that SJF is optimal (I don't think they consider average wait time and instead have criterion of minimizing total execution time).

- http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~yairamir/cs418/os2/sld026.htm
- http://os.etf.bg.ac.rs/OS2/Stud/Rad01/sjf.htm

From what I have been able to figure out about this problem, it appears that one would need to exhaustively list all possible schedules (permutations) of jobs. But I am not sure if there is a dynamic programming based approach that could allow one to get to an optimal solution without having to exhaustively find average wait time for all possible permutations.

**Problem:** A list of job request times and job length times is given in an array of `(r_i, t_i)` for `n` different jobs. `r_i` represents when the job request comes in, which is the arrival time or request time of the job, and `t_i` represents the time units that job takes to execute. There is only one person who handles jobs and can work only on one job at a time.

Compute the minimum average wait time for an given set of `N` jobs with input array `(r_i, t_i)`?

**Example:** list `(r_i, t_i)`: `job-1(0, 3), job-2(2, 5), job-3(3, 2)`

If the jobs are done in the order `job-1, job-2, job-3`, then:

Wait time for `job-1` = job end time - job request time = 3-0

Wait time for `job-2` = 8-2 = 6

Wait time for `job-3` = 10-3 = 7

So the average wait time is: (3 + 6 + 7) / 3.

But if these jobs are done in the order `job-1, job-3, job-2`: average wait time is: `(3+2+8)/3 = 13/3`, which is better than the original order. So the minimum average wait time is 13/3 time units.

**Edit:**

1. wait time for a job is being defined as (finish time - arrival or request time). One could also call it turnaround time. The problem is one of minimizing total wait time/N, which would be the same as one of minimizing the total wait time if one assumed a different definition of wait time as (job start time - job arrival time).
2. Example of SJF (shortest job first) not giving optimal schedule:

J1 (1, 5)
J2 (2, 2)
J3 (0, 3)

Shortest job j2. But choosing j3, j2, j1 is better schedule (tot wait time = 3+3+9) than choosing j2 first in j2, j3, j1 (wait time = 4+7+11)

3. Another example:
   J1 (0, 100)
   J2 (1, 2)

At the time 0, shortest job is J1. J1-J2 as the schedule gives total wait time of 100+102. J2-J1 schedules gives the best total wait time of 3+103.

Comment: Well waiting time is the time the process should wait for to start its execution from its arrival. The one you are calculating is [**turn around**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnaround_time) time.

Comment: you need to note that you have to make less people wait. When you schedule a job of start time S and end time E, every job that starts between S (inclusive) and E will now have the same start time (E, in this case), so you have to pick now the one that starts in E and have the minimum duration, so that everybody will wait the minimum time possible.

Comment: Can anyone show me an example that shortest job first will not produce an optimal solution? Thanks

Comment: can we complete job partially, switch to another job and then switch back??

Comment: @sanketmakanu answered your q in the edit of OP. Even with the alternate defn of wait time, it seems the schedule with the best turnaround time will have the best wait time.

Comment: @ tushar assume you can't but that shouldnt change the general approach much.

Comment: @Daniel that's just part of the picture. You may have multiple jobs ready to start at E. How would you choose? Simply choosing shortest job first doesn't guarantee optimal wait time.

Comment: @petarPetrovic added the example about SJF in the OP edit.

Comment: @JoeBlack yes, it guarantee optimal wait time. Consider that you have N people and in the current time just some of them can do the job. You must choose one of these people to do the job, and if you choose the one with the minimum time, N-1 people will wait the minimum time possible.

Comment: if you choose one of the people who can do the job and his time is not the minimum (between all people who can job), all the N-1 people left will wait more time than necessary.

Comment: @daniel No it doesn't. Added another example to OP to show tha SJF is not optimal for total wait time.

Comment: I wasn't considering this was possible... I thought if a person is schedule for the current time and other person not, then the first person should enter anyway

Comment: @daniel that's the point of providing all arrival times in advance. that's what makes the problem complex. as i said greedy SJF solution wouldn't be optimal.

Comment: @JoeBlack Thanks, do you think shortest available job first will work? i.e. when the worker is not working, choose the shortest job that it can work on or wait if there are no job.

Comment: @petar No it doesn't, it's explained with an example in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Something is not clear in your description : is preemption allowed ? i.e. is it possible to stop one job, start another one, and finish the job later. In both case, you can look at [this website](http://schedulingzoo.lip6.fr/) in order to know if your problem is NP-hard or polynomially solvable.

- If **preemption is allowed**, the problem is **easy to solve** and is written 1|pmtn;rj|∑Cj
- If **preemption is not allowed**, 1|rj|∑Cj is **NP-hard**, so there is no way that you find a greedy algorithm to solve your problem.

Moreover, looking at the sum of the completion times or the sum of waiting times is strictly equivalent, you just have to add / remove the sum of release dates and processing times.

Comment: Assume no premption as everything about the job arrival, exec times is known in advance. So one can definitely compute the optimal answer, it's just that it involves enumerating all possible schedules and seems NP complete. Is there an efficient way? SJF is said to be provably optimal in the links in OP but *may be* it doesn't apply to wait times.

Comment: Shortest Job First is optimal if all the jobs are available (i.e. rj=0 for all jobs). When there are release dates, Shortest Job Remaining (a variant of SJF) is optimal when preemption is allowed. But when there is release dates and no preemption, it is NP-hard.

Comment: If you agree with the answer, could you please validate it to make it clearer plse ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like **Job Shop Scheduling** which is **NP-complete** (which is fancy way of saying that today no one knows how to solve it optimally in reasonable time and scale out).

Look into algorithms such as a **Construction Heuristic** followed by a Local Search (such as **Tabu Search**). Those work best as proven by academic compo's such as MISTA 2013. For related implementations, see my open source [Project Job Scheduling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c) and [Task assigning optmization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksXjQ851RAU) implementations/video's.

Comment: I disagree, it is not a Jobshop problem, it is a one-machine problem.

Comment: Agreed, I missed that req.